# How to find exact location [user's possion not server possion] using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web, openlayers

I'm building a website and I have a button when I click on it, it shows me the internet server location instead of mine.
Does someone have a way of finding the exact user location?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html

Comment: @Meowster, It's not accurate.